# Ant Design components style not loading correctly

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

Recently I decided to  build my own setup for react & webpack 
So I faced some problems with UI libraries like **antd** or **Bulma**  when import component like button the style of it doesn't work

this is my index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import './index.css';

const Index = () => (
     <div>
         <Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
     </div>
  )
;

ReactDom.render(<Index/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

and this is my output

[image: Output]

(I uploaded the image on imgur because I'm not allowed to upload images on StackOverflow until I got 10 reputations)

this is my webpack setting code

```js
const path= require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports={
    entry:path.resolve(__dirname,'src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },


    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                use:"babel-loader",
                exclude:/node_modules/,
            },

            {
                test:/\.(css|scss)$/,
                use:[
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            modules: true,
                            camelCase: true,
                            localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                        },
                    },
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },

            {
                test:/\.less/,
                use:[
                    "less-loader",
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            bypassOnDebug: true,
                            disable: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                test:/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader: "url-loader",
                    options:{
                        limit:8000
                    }
                }

            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/index.html')
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, here's how I managed to solve it;

**Replace your webpack rule for less files with this:**

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: [
     { loader: "style-loader" },
     { loader: "css-loader" },
     { loader: "less-loader", options: { javascriptEnabled: true } }
  ]
}
```

**NB:** You should have style-loader, css-loader and less-loader installed.

**Import antd.less instead of antd.css**

In your index.js file, use `import "antd/dist/antd.less"` instead of `import "antd/dist/antd.css"` ensure you have less installed too.

Hope this helps!!